# Zend Framework - Handle an application with users and members

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, model

I was wondering how to handle separately users and members in an application where all registered users are considered as **users**, and users who have a team, are considered as **members**. Others users are *guest*.

Basically, a simple user can find a team, receive a team request, etc. A member can see his team profile, see other members, and do a lot of more things relative to members and his team.

Currently, users, members and teams are handle in three different classes, all of them represent their database table structure.

So I have 3 tables in my database as follows:

[image: MySQL Workbench]

And I have for example this class to represent a user:

```
class Lib_Model_Users_User implements Zend_Auth_Adapter_Interface, Zend_Acl_Role_Interface
{
    protected $_gateway;
    protected $_roleId;

    protected $_member = null;
    protected $_team = null;

    protected $_data = array(
        'user_id'       => null,
        'email'         => null,
        'password'      => null, 
        'first_name'    => null, 
        'last_name'     => null,
        'gender'        => null,
        'address'       => null,
        'city'          => null,
        'country'       => null,
        'postal_code'   => null, 
        'phone_mobile'  => null,
        'phone_home'    => null,
        'date_of_birth' => null,
        'occupation'    => null,
        'active'        => false,
        'created_on'    => null,
        'last_login'    => null,
        'last_update'   => null);

    public function __construct($data, $gateway)
    {
        $this->setGateway($gateway);
        $this->populate($data);

        if (!isset($this->user_id)) {
            if (!isset($this->email)) {
                if (!isset($this->first_name, $this->last_name))
                    throw new Lib_Exception('Initial data must contain an email or a user id or a pair firstname/lastname');
            }
        }
    }

    public function setMember($data)
    {
        $gateway = new Lib_Model_Teams_Gateway();
        $this->_member = $gateway->createMember($data);
    }

    public function getMember($status = 'active')
    {
        if (null === $this->getTeam()) {
            return null;
        }

        if (null === $this->_member) {
            $this->_member = $this->getTeam()->getMember($this->user_id);
        }

        if (is_string($status)) {
            $status = array($status);
        }

        foreach ($status as $state) {
            if ($this->_member->status == $state) {
                return $this->_member;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public function getTeam($active = true)
    {
        if ($this->_team === null) {
            $this->_team = $this->getGateway()->fetchTeam($this->user_id, $active);
        }
        return $this->_team;
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $gateway = $this->getGateway();
        $dbTable = $gateway->getDbTable();
        $row = $dbTable->find($this->user_id)->current();
        if ($row) {
            foreach ($this->_data as $key => $value) {
                $row->$key = $value;
            }
            return $row->save();
        }
        $this->user_id = $dbTable->insert($this->_data);
        return $this->user_id; 
    }

    public function getRoleId()
    {
        if (null === $this->_roleId)
            $this->_roleId = $this->user_id;
        return $this->_roleId;
    }

    ..........
    // etc.
    ..........
}
```

As you can see, this class is very "stick" to my database fields, I don't know if it's the best way to do it though.

My Members model is basically the same thing, except that it represents the "team_users" table and it doesn't have the set/getMembers methods but have methods relative to members.

Now, you understand how hard is it to manage such a thing, each time I want to get a member, I need to check if a user has a team, if so, I create a member instance using `getMember()`, etc.

From the member side, it's hard to get an information about a member such as his `first_name`, I always need to check the `user_id`, create a user instance and get his `first_name`.

How can I handle this kind of thing? I was thinking maybe my Member model should just extends the Users model since a member is also a user? Is it a good idea? How would you do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Unrelated -- what's the modelling software you've created that screenshot with?

Comment: Ah nice, never tried it. Downloading now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model it the way the things are, regardless how your database is structured - that will turn out to work best in most cases.

- As a member is some type of user, the Member class should extend the User class.
- Only the Member class should have a method getTeam(), as only members have a team and normal users don't.

I don't think that there really is a beautiful solution to handle your exact situation. But how about something like this?

```
$user = new User($data, $gateway);
if ($user->hasTeam()) {
    $user = Member::fromUser($user); // returns a new instance of 'Member'
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have another question though. How and where to determine which class should I instantiate? Should I use a factory that creates a user or a member according to his status (is or not in the teamusers table)?

Comment: That is what I meant to illustrate with my example: I would always create an User instance, then check if that user has a Team and if so, transform that User instance in a Member instance.

Comment: Thank you for this explaination!!